# How to copy events from one Sharepoint calendar to another?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I created a calendar in Sharepoint. It uses the old sharepoint apps. I've populated it with 100+ events.

How can I copy all of those events from this Sharepoint calendar to another blank Sharepoint calendar?

Answer (score 4):

Because the second calendar list is still **blank**, so you can use the `Save list as a template` option to save your list structure with its contents.

- Open your list > List setting
- Click on "Save list as Template" and check `Include Content`

[image]

- Then use this template to create your new calendar list.

---

**See Also**

- [Save list as a template is missing in SharePoint Online](https://debug.to/1043/save-list-as-template-is-missing)
- [Missing save site as template SharePoint Online](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 2):

Besides using list template, you can also use PowerShell/PnP PowerShell to copy events to the new list, but it will need a bit of configuration ahead.

See a sample script here:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
Function Copy-ListItems() {
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceListName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetListName
    )   
    Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Cred = Get-Credential
        $Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
     
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred
 
        #Get the Source List and Target Lists
        $SourceList = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($SourceListName)
        $TargetList = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($TargetListName)
     
        #Get All Items from Source List
        $SourceListItems = $SourceList.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
        $Ctx.Load($SourceListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     
        #Get All fields from Source List & Target List
        $SourceListFields = $SourceList.Fields
        $Ctx.Load($SourceListFields)
        $TargetListFields = $TargetList.Fields
        $Ctx.Load($TargetListFields)       
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Get each column value from source list and add them to target
        ForEach($SourceItem in $SourceListItems) {
            $NewItem =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
            $ListItem = $TargetList.AddItem($NewItem)       
  
            #Map each field from source list to target list
            Foreach($SourceField in $SourceListFields) { 
                #Skip Read only, hidden fields, content type and attachments
                If((-Not ($SourceField.ReadOnlyField)) -and (-Not ($SourceField.Hidden)) -and ($SourceField.InternalName -ne  "ContentType") -and ($SourceField.InternalName -ne  "Attachments") ) {
                    $TargetField = $TargetListFields | where { $_.Internalname -eq $SourceField.Internalname}
                    if($TargetField -ne $null)
                    {
                        #Copy column value from source to target
                        $ListItem[$TargetField.InternalName] = $SourceItem[$SourceField.InternalName] 
                    }
                }
            }
            $ListItem.update()
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
 
        write-host  -f Green "Total List Items Copied from '$SourceListName' to '$TargetListName' : $($SourceListItems.count)"
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Copying List Items!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "<SiteURL>"
$SourceListName = "<SourceList>"
$TargetListName = "<TargetList>"
 
#Call the function to copy list items
Copy-ListItems -siteURL $SiteURL -SourceListName $SourceListName -TargetListName $TargetListName
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Copy List Items from One List to Another using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-copy-list-items-to-another-list-using-powershell.html)